# 'git add .' leaves all files untracked

Tags: git

I was able to run 'git add .' and commit twice just a few hours ago, however, after making some changes in some files in the project it has suddenly stopped adding files. I even tried deleting the repo (.git folder) and running 'git init', 'git add .', but it [doesn't add a single file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLDL0.png). However, it *does* look like [it is adding files when I run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdSe2.png), but nothing is actually added.

There is no .gitignore in the repository, and my global gitignore doesn't have any entry that should make any difference here. I am able to add everything manually, it's just 'git add .', 'git add *', etc. that don't work.

I have tried everything I can think of, but since I'm quite new to git that isn't a lot, and I can't find any solutions online.

Comment: What does `git status` say?  Do you have any files that are staged or are unstaged for commit?

Comment: did you run `git commit -m "<commit message>"` after you added your files?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KLDL0.png That's what I get when I run git status. This is with a completely new repository, right after running 'git init'. The hidden '.git'-folder doesn't show with 'ls' in windows, but it is there.
And yes, I've tried committing but it tells me there is nothing to commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it after an hour of headache. I had added a nodejs module that had some files whose paths were too long for Windows (even though the repo was located in C:\node\app, node sure doesn't like Windows). Running 'npm dedupe' fixed it.